# Why only working when arguments have a length >= 3: R function

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I have made a function so that it works when its arguments each have a length `>= 2`.

But I'm wondering why the function only works when its argument have each have a length of `>= 3`!

Am I missing something? (Any fix so the function works when length of its args are each of 2 as well?)

[***Note:*** I always expect the output of function (i.e., `CI`) to be a matrix with 2 columns, `length(n)` rows, except when `length(n) == 2`. When `length(n) == 2` I expect the output to have 1 row, and 2 columns.]

```
abc <- function(n, yes, a, b = a){

  p <- list()

 for(i in 1:length(n)){
   p[[i]] <- rbeta(1e3, a[i] + yes[i], b[i] + (n[i] - yes[i]))
   }
 ps <- combn(p, 2, FUN = function(x) x[[1]]- x[[2]])

 CI <- matrix(NA, length(n), 2)

 for(i in 1:length(n)){
 CI[i, ] <- quantile(ps[, i], c(.025, .975))
   }
 CI
  }
```

For example:

```
  abc(n = c(10, 20, 30), yes = rep(5, 3), a = rep(1, 3)) # Works well :-)

  abc(n = c(10, 20), yes = rep(5, 2), a = rep(1, 2))  # Doesn't work! :-(
  # Error in ps[, i] : subscript out of bounds
```

Comment: What output do you expect? What do you get? Can you describe in words what your function is supposed to do? "Works" and "doesn't work" are not very descriptive. Does "doesn't work" mean R crashes? Hangs? Errors? Warnings? Not the output you want (how is it different?)? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is easy fix to problem. Replace `length(n)` with `ncol(ps)` while creating result matrix and running `for loop` to copy values to `CI`. It makes more sense as number of combinations generate by 'combn`will more than actual length of`n`.

```
abc <- function(n, yes, a, b = a){

  p <- list()

  for(i in 1:length(n)){
    p[[i]] <- rbeta(1e3, a[i] + yes[i], b[i] + (n[i] - yes[i]))
  }

  str(p)

  ps <- combn(p, 2, FUN = function(x) x[[1]]- x[[2]])


  CI <- matrix(NA, ncol(ps), 2)

  for(i in 1:ncol(ps)){
    CI[i, ] <- quantile(ps[, i], c(.025, .975), na.rm = TRUE)
  }
  CI
}


#Results
#> abc(n = c(10, 20, 30), yes = rep(5, 3), a = rep(1, 3))
#           [,1]      [,2]
#[1,] -0.10141014 0.5774627
#[2,]  0.02638096 0.6159326
#[3,] -0.12473451 0.3069135

#> abc(n = c(10, 20), yes = rep(5, 2), a = rep(1, 2))
#           [,1]      [,2]
#[1,] -0.1228497 0.5304606
```

Comment: Do you expect you function to work when `length(n)` is more than 3? If yes then please note that `CI` will not have sufficient number of rows to store all combinations.

Comment: @morouzian silly me. The actual fix is even simpler. Just use `ncol(ps)` instead of `length(n)` while creating matrix and copying results.